# How to select column value from a nested table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I created 1 object.

```
create type tab_billing as object(invoice_no number, 
                                    customername varchar2(100)
                                  );
```

Now i created a table with the object as a column.

```
CREATE TABLE tab1 (col1 number,COL2 tab_billing);
```

Is there anyway I can ONLY select `invoice_no` from the tab1.

```
select col2 from tab1;
```

Is givng me both `invoice_no` and `customername`. `Substr` function is not working here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can query the column value's object field directly, but to avoid confusing [the object name resolution](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements009.htm#SQLRF51132) steps you have to supply and use a table alias:

```
select t1.col2.invoice_no from tab1 t1;
```

This is mentioned [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e11822/adobjbas.htm#ADOBJ7080):

> To avoid inner capture and similar problems resolving references, Oracle Database requires you to use a table alias to qualify any dot-notational reference to subprograms or attributes of objects.

Qualifying the column with the the table name isn't enough; using `select tab1.col2.invoice_no from tab1` gets ORA-00904. You have to use a table alias - although, slightly bizarrely, it still works if the alias is the same as the table name, so `select tab1.col2.invoice_no from tab1 tab1` (i.e. aliasing `tab1` as `tab1`, which is normally redundant) works too.

Quick demo:

```
create type tab_billing as object(invoice_no number, 
                                    customername varchar2(100)
                                  );
/

Type TAB_BILLING compiled

CREATE TABLE tab1 (col1 number,COL2 tab_billing);

Table TAB1 created.

insert into tab1 values (1, tab_billing(42, 'Test'));

1 row inserted.

select t1.col2.invoice_no from tab1 t1;

                        COL2.INVOICE_NO
---------------------------------------
                                     42
```

Comment: Its bit strange ,,I used select col2.invoice_no 
from tab ; --It didnt work. But with alias its working.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`TREAT`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions234.htm#SQLRF06148):

```
SQL> create type tab_billing as object(invoice_no number,
  2                                      customername varchar2(100)
  3                                    );
  4  /

Type created.

SQL> CREATE TABLE tab1 (col1 number,COL2 tab_billing);

Table created.

SQL> insert into tab1 values (1, tab_billing(10, 'ten')) ;

1 row created.

SQL> select col1,
  2         TREAT(col2 AS tab_billing).invoice_no as invoice_no,
  3         TREAT(col2 AS tab_billing).customername as customername
  4  from tab1;

  COL1 INVOICE_NO CUSTOMERNAME
------ ---------- --------------------
     1         10 ten
```